# How to list all available predicates in Virtuoso?

Tags: sparql, virtuoso, triplestore

I am a beginner in `Virtuoso` and `sparql` and my question is, how can I list all the available `predicates` in my `triplestore`?

For example, if my query is:

```
sparql 
select * {
<http://my.domain.com/catalog/element/item55> ?p ?o.
}
```

I get

```
p                                            | o
----------------------------------------------------------------
http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#label   | Item 55
http://my.domain.com/catalog#propertyX       | ABC
```

How can I retrieve a list of all the predicates that are available in my triplestore?

Comment: Using a variable as subject instead of a URI that denotes a resource. And then select the predicate variable. This should be easily understandable once you read a SPARQL tutorial and know how RDF data is structured.

Comment: What does "available" mean? You can query for all predicates in use in triples in the store, but any URI is "available" for use as a predicate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will list all predicates:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?p { ?s ?p ?o }
```